# Getting the list of ASCII values from term in Prolog

Tags: prolog, ascii

I am using SWI-Prolog version 7.6.3 and I recently encounter a problem for converting a term that combines number and alphabet into its list of ASCII values.

I know that we can obtain the list of ASCII values of a particular term using `name/2` predicate. For example, if I want to get the ASCII value of the term `ab` or `'ab'`, then we can use `name(ab,X)`. Prolog simply outputs `X = [97, 98]`, 97 and 98 are respectively the ASCII values of a and b.

The predicate `name/2` also works for numbers. If I want to get the ASCII values of the term `123` or `'123'`, then we can use `name(123,X)`. Again, Prolog simply outputs `X = [49, 50, 51]` where 49, 50, and 51 are correspondingly the ASCII values of 1, 2, and 3.

However, the predicate `name/2` does not work if I combine number and alphabet in one term. For example, I expect that `name(2a,X)` returns `X = [49, 97]` and `name(3b,X)` returns `X = [50,98]`. However, the interpreter gives the error exception saying that an operator is expected.

I notice that the problem only occurs if the term begin with number. I check in the interpreter that `name(a2,X)` returns `X = [97, 49]` as expected.

How do I solve this problem? Or this condition inherently cannot be handled in Prolog?

Comment: Use `'3a'` to denote the atom, and better yet, use `atom_chars/2`!

Comment: @mat: Exactly what I thought when I read the question. If you could post this as an answer I could  upvote it ... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`3a` is not a Prolog atom. To make it an atom, write it in single quotes:

**`'3a'`**

Also, check out **`atom_chars/2`** to relate atoms to lists of *characters*!